# Default value for attribute constructor?

Tags: c#, attributes

I'm getting this error,

> error CS0182: An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

When I try to write something like this

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class UrlAttribute : Attribute
{
    public UrlAttribute(string pattern, string name=null)
    {
        // ...
```

It doesn't even show a line number, but it disappears when I take out that `=null` bit.

Actually, the error only occurs *both* when I provide a default value *and* rely on it (i.e., I omit it) like so

```
    [Url("/index")]
```

I'm curious to know why this? How is "null" not a constant expression?

Comment: I received feedback from Microsoft, and updated my response accordingly.

Comment: @kbrimington: Thanks for the update! Sounds like we'll have to wait before the fix is released... oh well, it's hardly critical :)

Comment: object name=null also gives this error.

Comment: As of Visual Studio 2012 Update 3, with a .net 4.0 project being built - this problem still exists.

Comment: This bug is still present in VS 2013

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm calling 'bug'.

I hope you don't mind, I reported the bug to Microsoft.

***UPDATE:***

I received the following feedback from Microsoft today, emphasis added.

> Thanks for reporting this issue you've
>   encountered with Visual Studio!
>
> We've fixed up optional string
>   parameters on attributes in our code.
>   ***You'll see this fix in the version of
>   Visual Studio after VS 2010.***
>
> Alex Turner
>
> Program Manager
>
> Visual Basic and C# Compiler

Comment: Don't mind at all. I get a 404 when I follow that link though. It asked me to log in, and then said the page wasn't found.

Comment: @Mark: Strange. I just tried it out and it worked just fine. Perhaps it's a permissions thing. I'll keep you posted. I did receive an automated confirmation letter indicating it was being routed to the proper team. We'll see what happens.

Comment: It did mention permissions -- "The content that you requested cannot be found or you do not have permission to view it." So that might be it.

Comment: Huh. Interesting they gave a 404 instead of a 401, then, eh?

Comment: Well.. I just said "404" because it said "Page not found" \*runs off to check the headers\* It actually sent a 500.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes already provide default-able arguments.  You simply create public properties on the attribute and those can be assigned in the attribute instantiation process.  It already works, it's already well-understand and it's consistent with how framework attributes work.  So...why not just use that mechanism instead of trying to redundantly add default parameters to the constructor?

Comment: That wasn't the question :) But the reason "why" is because C# 4 added named parameters. With Attributes, it would seem that we now have *two* ways of defining named parameters, except that we don't, because this one raises an error; I was trying to keep the app consistent by sticking with one method. Nevertheless, I'm not saying it's a good idea to add default args, I'm just wondering *why* we can't.

Comment: It might be a bug, but I don't think it's critical because there is already a better way to do it.  Sorry that C# isn't fully orthogonal.

Comment: For me that's definitely a bug. You can compile the code with the definition of the attribute, but whatever code that uses it can't compile.