# Attribute argument must be a constant expression

Tags: c#, interface, attributes

Could someone please explain to me why the following interface definition compiles with error in Visual Studio 2010?

```
   [IncompleteCodePort(SourceOriginType.Other, "This should be a GL abstraction depending on what OpenGL API will be used")]
    public interface IGL
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if provided function is available or supported by graphics API
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="funcName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        bool IsFunctionAvailable(string funcName);

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if provided function is supported as extension by graphics API
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="funcName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        bool IsExtensionAvailable(string funcName);
    }



public class IncompleteCodePortAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public SourceOriginType SourceOriginType { get; private set; }
        public string SourceUrl { get; private set; }
        public string Reason { get; private set; }


        public IncompleteCodePortAttribute(SourceOriginType originType, string reason, string sourceUrl = null)
        {
            SourceOriginType = originType;
            SourceUrl = sourceUrl;
            Reason = reason;
        }
    }

    public enum SourceOriginType
    {
        CodePlex,
        WorldWindJdk,
        StackOverflow,
        Other
    }
```

and error I am getting is:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

If I remove the custom attribute, I get no compile errors.

Comment: What is `IncompleteCodePort`? Post all its constructors.

Comment: I was able to compile with a dummy IncompleteCodePort class. I believe you are missing some information here.

Comment: If you are using `Enum` in the `IncompleteCodePort` class, don't.  Use `SourceOriginType` instead.

Comment: My bad.  Posted this way too late.  I have added the IncompleteCodePortAttribute definition.

Comment: I take what I said before back, it seems the code actually *doesn't* compile fine under VS2010 (but it does under VS2012).

Comment: It's a bug in the c# compiler. It has been fixed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290853/attribute-argument-must-be-a-constant-error-when-using-an-optional-parameter-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the C# compiler in VS2010 (the code compiles fine under VS2012). It looks like the compiler doesn't treat the `null` in the default value of the parameter as constant.

This code doesn't compile:

```
[IncompleteCodePort()]
interface IGL
{}

class IncompleteCodePortAttribute : Attribute
{
    public IncompleteCodePortAttribute(string sourceUrl = null)
    {}
}
```

with the mentioned error message (“An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type”), but confusingly without a source code location.

Some examples of declaration of the attribute that do work:

```
class IncompleteCodePortAttribute : Attribute
{
    public IncompleteCodePortAttribute(string sourceUrl = "")
    {}
}
```

```
class IncompleteCodePortAttribute : Attribute
{
    private const string Null = null;

    public IncompleteCodePortAttribute(string sourceUrl = Null)
    {}
}
```

```
class IncompleteCodePortAttribute : Attribute
{
    public IncompleteCodePortAttribute()
        : this(null)
    {}

    public IncompleteCodePortAttribute(string sourceUrl)
    {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Strangely enough, I opened solution in VS2012, went back into VS2010 and reloaded, now it compiles.

Comment: It did, now it does not compile.  I just removed the optional constructor parameter and overloaded the constructor.  Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290853/attribute-argument-must-be-a-constant-error-when-using-an-optional-parameter-in

Comment: Good to know we are getting a service pack with this fixed... O wait.